# PHP: Connect to MySQL using Socket Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

Due an odd request from a customer I need to connect to Mysql database using [Socket Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) from PHP. I have been searching for ways to create a connection but no luck.

Any ideas? is this possible?

Comment: You need to make sure the Linux user that makes that makes the unix socket authentication to mysql, is the same user as created in MySQL. What user does your PHP scripts run as? Is this php-fpm? mod_php?

Comment: @danblack php-fpm

Comment: @danblack is not possible to specify different user on connection?

Comment: yes. see the bottom of the page you linked to. I think this is time to show what user you created, what user the php-fpm runs under, how the application connects, and what the connection error is.

Comment: @danblack, yes I saw that, but that section explains how to connect through terminal, how can I do it from a php file? how the connection string would look like?

Comment: `'mysql:dbname=testdb;user=php-fpm;unix_socket=/path/to/socket'`

Comment: @danblack Thanks!, I guess I can change user by anyone who exist in linux and/or mysql, right?