# How unsecured is MySQL database with localhost only access but no password

Tags: mysql

We have a dedicated server with MySQL and other components

- MySQL port is blocked by the firewall and hence no incoming connections to that port is possible.
- Database access is only granted to local users  like 'me'@'127.0.0.1' so that only apps/servers running on that server can access the database

In this case, having no password or the default password any less secure than having a password?

IMO, password should not make difference in this case but would like to learn from MySQL and security experts here if I have missed something.

Thanks

Comment: I would say that if an attacker manages to get shell access to your server, you're in pretty deep trouble no matter. Also, often secrets are stored as shell variables in servers so even with password, it's likely that an attacker could read the password in the shell variable and use that. So in general I would not worry but then of course there might always be very particular usecases. What's the SSH possibilities on the server?

Comment: rather than no password, you should consider using unix socket authentication ```unix_socket authentication plugin```. That way, only unix user named 'me' can login as user 'me'@'localhost'

Comment: @fast-reflexes if they can access shell, they can anyway reset MySQL root password so that's not the valid. But thanks for your answer

Comment: @Kristian thanks, I will look into unix socket option but most apps we have right now accesses using IP address.  Do you see issues with local IP?

Comment: @Jim can they? How so, just curious :) I mean it depends right ... Bill has got a good point in the answer.

Comment: I don't know if your app can connect to mysql via unix socket or not (it depends if their mysql connector supports it or not), but for one example, php can do it https://stackoverflow.com/q/55585768/3706717

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the option [skip-networking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking) just in case the firewall becomes compromised.

As for the password, if an attacker gets shell access but not superuser shell access, then having a password would be a good idea, assuming the password is stored in a file that is not readable by the attacker.

There's almost no reason to avoid a password, because you don't have to type it every time if you store the password in the `.my.cnf` or `.mylogin.cnf`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html

But if the attacker gains superuser access, then they can read any file anyway, so having a password doesn't help. A superuser could also restart mysqld and disable authentication as documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: thanks, that was my thought too that unless someone accesses shell, password is redundant in local host case. We have some automatic script settings which is replicated across instances and hence contemplating using no or default password.

Comment: You can still use an options file with user/password credentials in it, and I have done so when I developed automation scripts.